# How to convert double value to integer value in MIPS?

Tags: mips

if I have in MIPS :
li.d $f0,4.5

My question is :
How to convert double value to integer value in MIPS...
How I can cast the value in register $f0 to 4 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sequence that works. You can use `$f0` instead of `$f2` if you want:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    li.d        $f0,4.5
    cvt.w.d     $f2,$f0             # now f2 will have 4

    # just to print it as an integer
    mfc1        $a0,$f2
    li          $v0,1
    syscall

    # exit program
    li          $v0,10
    syscall
```